# SQL Server error 0x5 (15404) - could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, redgate

I am using SQL Server 2019 (15.0.4298.1). I am sysadmin on SQL Server and a member of the admin group on the server box.

This is a Dev server, which has 5 main user databases, which I set up, using AD groups for permissions. I am a member of the Admin AD group, which is a member of `db_owner`. The dbo user uses my credentials (presumably because I created the databases using my credentials). As such, I am not able to add myself back into the database as a user.

On Friday last week, I set up Redgate SQL Source Control and linked it to Bitbucket via Sourcetree. All was fine until I tried to run the Redgate lock object script. Since this, I have been receiving the 0x5 error whenever I try to run any scripts (even SP create or alter).

Most of the advice out there suggests to change the database owner to the sa account. However, I am unable to do this, as I get the error:

> Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user '<myusername>’, error code 0x5. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Server Name: [myservername]
> Error Number: 15404
> Severity: 16
> State: 19
> Procedure: RG_SQLSourceControl_DDLTrigger

I would appreciate any advice on how to fix this without having to run a full server restore back to before the source control amendment.

Thank you.

I have tried to change the database owner, as recommended in various posts.  This caused the error to be returned.

I have checked the user details in the domain, and they are present and spelled correctly.

I have checked the user permissions in SQL Server and on the server machine - admin.

I have tried to restore the databases, but was unable to complete the restore process, as the process includes a step to create the database users (T-SQL script), which failed to run due to the same error.

Comment: Uninstall Redgate? If that fails then `DROP TRIGGER RG_SQLSourceControl_DDLTrigger ON DATABASE` or `ALL SERVER` maybe? Clearly there is a database or server trigger not working

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface.  That seems to have done the trick.  I wasn't aware of the DROP ON ALL SERVER and couldn't find in the databases.